# What is the resource url for accessing storage entities using client credential grant in azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, access-token, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to access storage account (blob and table) using credential grant. The access token is working for blob storage , but not for accessing table entities.

the code for creating

```
const data = querystring.stringify({
  client_id: this.appId,
  client_secret: this.appKey,
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  resource: 'https://storage.azure.com',
});
const config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + this.DirectoryId + '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0',
  data: data,
};
try {
  const result = await axiosInstance(config);
  return result.data.access_token;
} catch (error) {
  const errorData = error.response?.data ? error.response.data : null;
  const errorDescription = errorData && errorData.error_description ? errorData.error_description : null;
  if (errorDescription) {
    throw new Error(errorDescription);
  }
  throw error;
```

when i tried accessing for get all table entities, i'm getting the below error

*"This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.*

Comment: Checking the .NET SDK a bit, it does look like they use `https://storage.azure.com/.default` as the scope (not resource, they use AAD's v2 endpoint). Your resource should be equivalent to this though.. So I'm not 100% sure why it would not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply junnas. I have missed table data reader access in IAm.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK uses the scope `https://storage.azure.com/.default`, so that resource is correct.

In this case the issue seems to have been missing RBAC permissions to access the table.

Comment: yes. I have missed storagetablecontributor access